# How to write a custom event handler so that the message sent includes the event object?

Tags: event-handling, elm

If writing a custom event handler, how do I write it so that the message sent includes the event object? Or, can I read the event object before sending the message?

Comment: Please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem and ask about what you are trying to solve, instead of how to implement what you believe might be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you need access to something on click, just add it to the Msg Type, and pass it in your view.

IE:

type Msg = ButtonClicked MyObject | ...

and in your view:

button [ onClick (ButtonClicked model.myObject) ] [ text "button text" ]